# R alphanumeric string range

Tags: r, range, alphanumeric

I have managed to extract from a string all values starting with "N_", however I cant extracted precisely those with a certain range of numbers.
Is an R data frame and I have something like this

```
V1                                 N_words 
(N_R33A, N_R35B, N_T44N, J_T7B)    N_R33A, N_R35B, N_T44N
```

My desired output would be having a specific range of all the N_

```
V1                                 N_words (range 30-35)
(N_R33A, N_R35B, N_T44N, J_T7B)    N_R33A, N_R35B
```

The code I am using is but is only extracting N_ and I dont seem to be able to select a range, I am also creating a new column to my x data frame with the extracted words :

```
x$N_words = str_extract_all(x$V1, "N_([A-Z]|[0-9])+")
```

Comment: Are you columns literal strings or list-columns?

Comment: Why is the range `30` if 30 is not present?

Comment: `str_extract_all(x$V1, "N_([A-Z]3[0-5])[A-Z]")`

Comment: this unfortunately is returning me this: character(0)

Comment: I have some N_ with 30 as well, this is why I included it

Answer (score 0):

One option is modifying the regex:

```
x = "(N_R33A, N_R35B, N_T44N, J_T7B)"
str_extract_all(x, "N_[A-Z]3[0-5][A-Z]")
# [[1]]
# [1] "N_R33A" "N_R35B"
```

- matches `N_`
- followed by an uppercase letter (`[A-Z]`)
- followed by `3`
- followed by 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 (`[0-5]`) .
- followed by an uppercase letter (`[A-Z]`)

Comment: It returns "character(0) unfortunately